# send post request in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, post, joomla

I create a new module that send user information to the data base.
But i have trouble with post request!

```
<form action="send.php" id="send_c" method="post" >
<p>1</p>
<input type="text" name="pib_u" />
<p>2</p>
<input type="text" name="email_u" />
<p>3</p>
<input type="text" name="phone_u" />
<p>4</p>

<select>
<?php
foreach ($list as $item) {
    echo '<option>'.$item->cat_name.'</option>';
}
?>   
</select>

<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />

</form>
```

when i trying to send information from the form i get the 404 error with send.php 
PS: send.php in module folder

please help me to resolve this problem! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<form action="<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/your_modname/send.php';?>" id="send_c" method="post" > 

get request your with

$_POST['var_name'] or JRequest::getVar ('var_name');
```

Comment: or retrieve the data with JInput if it's Joomla 2.5!

Answer (score 1):

If you send the request to the same page where the module is loaded leave the action attribute empty.

```
<form action="" id="send_c" method="post" >
```

The way you wrote it it looks for {current url}send.php and it doesn't find it.

Comment: send.php is not the same page, this file in module folder and i need to open him in form action="send.php"

Comment: Can you post the whole URL that routes to your module